# Github Actions Release Drafter token error *github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

[image]

An error occurs in the git hub release drafter.

.github/workflows/release-drafter.yml:

```
name: Release Drafter
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  update_release_draft:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: release-drafter/release-drafter@v5
        with:
          config-name: release-drafter-config.yml
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MyToken }}
```

The release is not automatically generated.

Comment: When you look at the action logs, do  you see a value set in the environment for `GITHUB_TOKEN`? Is `MyToken` an existing secret? Are you sure you need a personal access token, and the standard `GITHUB_TOKEN` itself isn't sufficient?

Comment: I seted the my token.   secrets.ghp_*******************.